# Excluding certain modules from proguard Android Gradle Buildscript

Tags: java, android, gradle, proguard

I have a  Project structure of the following form:

`Root Project
+------ Module A
+------ Module B`

Now Module B is a huge project, but I use an API to access it, so I would like to load the classes of Module B at runtime. As such I would like to compile it but in a separate DEX file. I am able to compile a separate DEX file by the following gist:

https://gist.github.com/nickcaballero/7045993

In the debug compile mode this work fine since one can change the libraries being DEXed via the buildscript in this form

```
def libraryFiles = new ArrayList<?>()
        variant.dex.libraries.each {
            File file ->
                // Exclude Module B from Dex library list
                if (!file.absolutePath.contains("ModuleB/unspecified/classes.jar")) {
                    libraryFiles.add(file);
                }
        }

        variant.dex.libraries = libraryFiles
```

Now this works well since when not doing proguard, the `AndroidBuilder` simply uses `variant.dex.libraries` to create the DEX file and excluding it is easy. The pain comes when one needs to do proguard of the intermediate class. Since `ModuleB` is a compile time dependency (for the purpose of resource integration/layouts etc.) therefore its classes, get compiled into the build directory.

However when it is getting proguarded, the default proguard task defined in the Android Builder throws in the `classes.jar` file as `libraryJars`.

At the end of it, the task creates `classes-proguard` which contains all the classes from the above library Jars. This then gets DEXed, and the classes which were to be loaded via Runtime are present in it. Is there any way to exclude certain jars to not be fed into the default proguard task?

Comment: did you find any solution?